# Cannot add image to a Zabbix GUI

Tags: php, centos, db2, centos6, zabbix

I've compiled zabbix 3.0.7 (LTS) with db2.

Everything is working okay, but when I try to add a background image to the GUI, the following error occurs.

[image: screenshot]:

```
db2_execute(): Value Not Bound [adm.images.php:92 → CApiWrapper->__call() → CFrontendApiWrapper->callMethod() → CApiWrapper->callMethod() → CFrontendApiWrapper->callClientMethod() → CLocalApiClient->callMethod() → CImage->create() → db2_execute() in include/classes/api/services/CImage.php:226]

db2_execute(): Binding Error 3 [adm.images.php:92 → CApiWrapper->__call() → CFrontendApiWrapper->callMethod() → CApiWrapper->callMethod() → CFrontendApiWrapper->callClientMethod() → CLocalApiClient->callMethod() → CImage->create() → db2_execute() in include/classes/api/services/CImage.php:226]
```

I cannot add the image -- both the icon and background.

I've set the zabbix server to debug mode, but it doesn't display an error and the db2 Query error does not contain anything in the log.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

That's most likely a bug, and looks like you already have reported it at https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-11847 :)